# C# XML Serialization: Seralizizing Nullable Value Types (Want to Suppress "null" Values Without Decorators/Attributes/ShouldSerialize)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I'm working with code in C# trying to serialize an object to XML. *I cannot add XML attributes or extra properties (e.g. `bool ShouldSerializeFoo`) to this object.* Nor can I add any `[Xml*]` attributes to properties. I can only control the XML Serializer.

Some of the properties are nullable types (`int?` et al), and I would like them to not be serialized if they are null (i.e. `foo.HasValue` is false).

Is there a way to instruct the XML serializer in C# to skip over null properties of nullable value types? If not, is there a way to hook into `ShouldSerialize()` for every property so I can inject custom logic into it? (I can manually check if the value is a nullable type and do `HasValue` checking myself).

Given this C# class:

```cs
public class SomeObject
{
    public int? Foo { get; set; }
    public string? Bar { get; set; }
}
```

If I set `Foo` to `null` and `Bar` to `"Something"`, I'd like the XML output to be:

```xml
<SomeObject>
    <Bar>Something</Bar>
</SomeObject>
```

I am using something like this to invoke the serializer currently:

```cs
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

// Class code omitted

public string CreateXML(SomeObject objToSerialize)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new(objToSerialize.GetType());
    using StringWriter stringWriter = new();
    using XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, new() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true });
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, objToSerialize, new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty }));
    return stringWriter.ToString();
}
```

If what I want is impossible, I will resort to manually editing the serialized XML after the fact in order to remove them (regular expressions to find and replace `'nil'` elements with an empty string), but I would rather the serializer just skip those values in the first place.

Comment: There is no way to suppress output of nullable value types when null using attributes.  If you apply `[XmlElement(IsNullable = false)]` to `public int? Foo { get; set; }` you will get an exception *`IsNullable may not be set to 'false' for a Nullable<System.Int32> type`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/rH3j0t.  And since [`XmlAttributeOverrides`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides) only allows you to specify attribute overrides (and not `ShouldSerialize()` methods), there is no way to do this with `XmlAttributeOverrides` either.

Comment: So your options are 1) Subclass `XmlWriter` or `XmlTextWriter` and suppress output of null nodes (not impossible but not entirely trivial, you will have to buffer the element name until all its attributes are written).  2) Write to a temporary `XElement` hierarchy, remove the null nodes, then output to the result `string`.  Easy but requiring memory for the intermediate `XElement` hierarchy.  3) Write to a temporary string, remove the null nodes with a regex and write to the result string.  Easy or hard?  (I don't use regex's often) but requiring memory for the temp string.

Comment: Do you have a preference between those workarounds?

Comment: @dbc my solution indeed was to modify the outputted XML after the fact. And indeed I used regular expressions! I was hoping that there was a way to instruct the serializer to help me out here, but I guess I'm not going to find any joy in that direction.

Comment: Sounds good, but do note that XML embedded inside `CDATA` nodes is the bane of regex XML parsers.